# Veins Framework Tutorial Accident rate

Tags: omnet++, veins

Currently, I am doing some research scenarios with Veins framework. I modified the Veins example (which is in the tutorial) and made it use my network file and ran the simulation for 3000 step.

From the OMNeT++ console, I can see that there are lot of accidents scheduled and performed. May I know how these accidents are being scheduled? In what rate? For example 2 accidents per minute or 5 accidents per SUMO 15 steps?

Answer (score 1):

In omnetpp.ini at the mobility tab it is possible to specify which node, when and for how long the accident will occur, for example:

```
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 1
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentStart = 10s
*.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 1s
```

Another thing to care about is that [accident start is 
relative to the time where a node enters the simulation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/GdJcmnUUI8w).  If there aren't many accidents maybe you can specify these accidents manually.